# How could we write a query in MongoDB to select fields that their names vary?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a big JSON file, and I use MongoPy to parse it. I want to select some fields and save them in a new JSON file. Some field names vary. For instance in the following JSON example, I want to select "Detials" for all "id"s:

```
item = { "act": {
             "id1":[ {"Detials": {...}
                     "Values": {...}
                     },
                     {"Detials": {...}
                     "Values": {...}
                     },
                   ]
             "id2":[ {"Detials": {...}
                     "Values": {...}
                     },
                     {"Detials": {...}
                     "Values": {...}
                     },
                   ]
            }

      };
```

Comment: Add a valid `json` item.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is difficult to use MongoDB to query fields with different names.

If you restructure your data a little, to turn "act" into an array of sub-documents then you can put the "id1" marker inside each sub-document - which will make it easier to query all the "Detials". For example, like this:

```json
{
    "act": [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "Detials": {...},
                    "Values": {...}
                },
                {
                    "Detials": {...},
                    "Values": {...}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "Detials": {...},
                    "Values": {...}
                },
                {
                    "Detials": {...},
                    "Values": {...}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If your data is in this structure, you can very easily query like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: {"$act"}},
    {$group: {_id: "allTheDetails", "Detials" : {$push: "$act.data.Detials"}}}
])
```

And that will return an array of every "Detials" block.

Comment: Thank for your answer. How can I convert  "act" into an array of sub-documents? The JSON file includes around 1M  "act", and around 4M "ids". So, at the same time, I'm looking for an optimal way.

Comment: @YNr Well, that's a different problem: too big a problem to be answered in comments here. There are a number of ways to do a static restructuring (e.g. [aggregating to a new collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) but you will have to reengineer your applications too.

Comment: If we don't consider the number of fields, how can I convert  "act" into an array of sub-documents?